# ServiceStack Validator - Request not injected

Tags: servicestack

I have a validator and I'm trying to use some session variables as part of the validation logic, however the base.Request is always coming back as NULL. I've added it in the lambda function as directed and also the documentation for Validation seems to be out of date as the tip in the [Fluent validation for request dtos](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#fluentvalidation-for-request-dtos) section mentions to use `IRequiresHttpRequest`, but the AbstractValidator class already implements `IRequiresRequest`.

This is my code:

```
public class UpdateContact : IReturn<UpdateContactResponse>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public List<Accounts> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateContactResponse : ResponseBase
{
    public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateContactValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateContact>
{
    public UpdateContactValidator(IValidator<AccountDetail> accountDetailValidator)
    {
        RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post | ApplyTo.Put, () => {
            var session = base.Request.GetSession() as CustomAuthSession;
            RuleFor(c => c.Reference).Must(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && session.Region.GetCountry() == RegionCodes.AU);
        });

        RuleFor(R => R.Accounts).SetCollectionValidator(accountDetailValidator);
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access to injected dependencies can only be done from within a `RuleFor()` lambda, delegates in a `RuleSet()` are executed on constructor initialization to setup the rules for that RuleSet.

So you need to change your access to `base.Request` to within `RuleFor()` lambda:

```
RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post | ApplyTo.Put, () => {
  RuleFor(c => c.Reference)
    .Must(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && 
    (Request.GetSession() as CustomAuthSession).Region.GetCountry() == RegionCodes.AU);
});
```

Comment: so this is more of a knowledge of "order of execution" which is specific to SS

Comment: @Jeff Nope not to do with the Request Pipeline, the `RuleSet()` lambda gets executed in the constructor before the dependencies are injected, the `RuleFor()` lambda's are executed on validation which has access to an properly injected Validators.

Comment: Thanks that works for a single level validation, but now when I add a nested validator `RuleFor(R => R.Accounts).SetCollectionValidator(accountDetailValidator);` the accountDetailValidator doesn't seem to resolve the Request object. I've also updated the question.

Comment: @vonec ok just added support for collection validators which should now be initialized with `IRequest` in latest v4.0.57 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).